# can I build javafx without start function

Tags: swing, javafx

I want to develop a javafx application which should not have a start function why?
When I am developing a swing application with `JFrame` I usually comment the
 
 `public static void main(String[] args)` 
function and build the jar. This ensures me if someone double clicks the jar file will not execute unless proper method. I use this .jar file into another java program which will call this jar and execute it.
I want same functionality in javafx application.
When I comment `public void start(Stage primaryStage)`  function in FX it gives error.
How should I do this.
Thanks in advance
Yogesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the launch parameters of JavaFX (which is just a beefed up version of the main method parameters).

Lets say we add a new mandatory parameter named `launch` to our application. You can check if someone (your code) has passed this parameter to the application and start or if the parameter is missing quit the application.

You can access the parameters anywhere in your `Application` class, but in your case `init()` seems to be a good place:

```
public class MyFXClient extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, String> mainParams = getParameters().getNamed();
        // TODO check if parameter "launch" is present..
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(MyFXClient.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now you can call the main method from outside and pass along the parameter with `--launch=test`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse
There I can export a project as "Runnable Jar-File" and "Jar-File".

If you want, that nobody double clicks the jar file, maybe you can use the "Jar-File" witch are not runnable

The difference between the two kinds of jar files are the "Runnable Jar-File" contains a Main-Class, and the other not.

Comment: ok but I use Netbeans IDE to develop my fx and other java application